# Quantizing Complex Klein gordon Field, how do they get rid of Crossed terms?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I was working through the exercises on Peskin and Schroeder specifically 2.2, I get the Following equation:
$ Q=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}(a_{p}^{\dagger}a_{p}-b_{p}^{\dagger}b_{p}+a_{p}^{\dagger}b_{-p}^{\dagger}-b_{-p}a_{p})$ 
 However i know the correct answer is $ Q=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}(a_{p}^{\dagger}a_{p}-b_{p}^{\dagger}b_{p})$  where Q is the conserved charge , i do not have any idea as to why the term   $a_{p}^{\dagger}b_{-p}^{\dagger}-b_{-p}a_{p}$ Disappears my first thought was that when appiled to a ket it is a constant that doesn't tell us anything and therefore we ignore it but i'm not really sure that is the Case , thanks in advance for your answers I've bee struggling with this one for a few days

Comment: Just check the algebra, Coefficients in front of that term is $E_p-E_{-p}$ which is equal and cancels.

Comment: There shouldn't be a mixed $ab$ term, check your calculations again. If you still can't find it, attach your derivation of $Q$ to the question.

Comment: thank you, just as you said  there should be no crossed terms, I really thought I had got the algebra right because an online solution got those terms as well but turns out they cancel out, thanks